# prevent image viewer from hanging when clicked too much

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to build some (simple) image viewer to be able to watch images from a site in a nice way with the possibility to navigate between the different images on one (part of a) page. My code thus far is demonstrated in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/231yahsz/).

The problem with this code though is the fact that if the user wants to skip some images and presses the next-button rapidly, the site hangs (and if pressed enough, it does not recover anymore and crashes). I hoped I would be able to avoid this when I interrupted the loading by using `$(window).stop()`, but that does not seem to do the trick. I've also tried something like

```
$(<img>).load(function() {
    $("aside img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
}).attr("src", root.attr("href"));
```

to load images asynchronously, but that does not seem to solve this issue either.

All by all I am quite fresh in the entire web-development thing and I don't seem to be able to find some understandable explanation on how to circumvent this problem. I heard something about ajax and that it allows for real asynchronous loading, but I also understood it is not really suitable for images...

So if anybody could guide me in the direction of a solution for this problem, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about disable the buttons on click and enable them when the function returns?

Comment: @LGSon I thought about it, but I would be more satisfied if I could allow users to navigate to a picture fastly(?) without having to leave the viewer.

Comment: Maybe a good start would be to take out the `$("#next").click(function() {`/`$("#prev").click(function() {` in `showInViewer` function and load that in some other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of a modification to only add one event handler to next/prev button as well as removing the DOM image element if a new image is requested should do the trick:

```
$(function() {
  $(".preview a").click(function(event) {
    $("aside").show();
    event.preventDefault();
    showInViewer($(this));
  });
  $("#exit").click(function() {
    $("aside").hide();
  });
});

var last;
$("#prev").click(function() {
  showInViewer(last.prev(".preview a"));
});
$("#next").click(function() {
  showInViewer(last.next(".preview a"));
});

function showInViewer(root) {
  last = root;
  $("aside img").remove();
  $("<img></img>").attr("src", root.attr("href")).appendTo("aside");
}
```

Comment: The main trick turned out to be to remove the event handlers from `showInViewer(root)` as also mentioned by @LGSon in the comments...